# Rest in peace, Robbie Coltrane, you were magical for us!

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Robbie Coltrane, probably best known for his performance as Rubeus Hagrid in the *Harry Potter* film series, [has passed away.](https://www.bbc.com/news/entertainment-arts-63261204)

> Actor Robbie Coltrane, who played Hagrid in the Harry Potter films, has died aged 72.
>
> In a statement, his agent Belinda Wright confirmed the actor died in hospital near Falkirk in Scotland.

Robbie was J.K. Rowling's first and only choice to play Hagrid, and what (in my opinion) a wonderful casting it was. I constantly am walking around putting on my best Hagrid (or Robbie I suppose) voice saying "I shouldn'ta said that" or "I shouldn'ta told you that".

I am sure Robbie will be missed by his family, friends, and colleagues. I speak for myself, but I also feel many in the community will agree his smile and larger than life personality will be missed... But let us take the wisdom of Hagrid's closest confidant's advice and say, "To the well-organized mind, death is but the next great adventure."

Comment: Gutted.. I use some form of “yer a wizard, Harry” at least twice a week. RIP big guy

Comment: Th Blackadder's Christmas Carol, he played the Ghost of Christmas Present as more or less the same character as Hagrid.

Comment: For me, he'll always be "Fitz" from the crime drama *Cracker* .  He was sublime in the role.